# SSH connection times out when trying to remotely connect to my personal computer from laptop on another network

Tags: ssh, port-forwarding

I have a desktop computer and a laptop. Both run Debian 9.5. Both have openssh installed.

On my desktop, when I run `ip a`, I see this as part of the output:

```
enp0s31f6: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000
  # Some other stuff
  inet 192.168.0.11
```

On my laptop, when I run `ssh myDesktopUsername@192.168.0.11`, I get this error after a while: `ssh: connect to host 192.168.0.11 port 22: Connection timed out`.

My desktop computer is connected to my Motorola router/modem by Ethernet cable. On the port forwarding section of my router/modem page, I have this rule.

[image]

My laptop is not on the same network as my desktop machine. Using my laptop, how do I remotely connect to my desktop via SSH?

Comment: Is the ssh server on 192.168.0.11 running? `systemctl status sshd.service`...

Comment: Yes. Output: `Active: active (running)`

Comment: Connection still times out without port forwarding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The address class 192.168.0.11 used for your desktop is a ["private" address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Private_network) which will not be accessible from outside this network. So port forwarding *is* required if your laptop is outside this network.

To connect to your desktop from outside the network, you need to know the "external" or WAN/internet IP address of your modem as it is the one doing the port forwarding. (It is only forwarding the port, it cannot forward the IP address!)

This address can usually be found by looking at the web page of your modem/router. However, many ISP's would *dynamically* reassign this IP address periodically, so it may not be a fixed address. In that case the problem is a bit harder to fix! There are also many solutions, but probably too complicated to explain here.